# Assembly writer vs compiler in VLIW architecture

Tags: compilers, assembly

I read this sentence in a book:

> In VLIW architecture, the compiler/and or assembly writer chooses instructions that can be executed in parallel.

What is the difference between assembly writer and compiler? Would an assembly writer also mean the same as assembler?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The "assembly writer" in that book is a human software developer who writes code in assembler language.

Comment: It doesn't mean a tool flow which converts to assembly language? Is compiler the only one that does it? (apart from interpreter).

Comment: 1. interpreter doesn't convert anything to assembly language. 2. Any tool that converts source code to assembly language is by definition a compiler.

Comment: @gnasher729 by your definition, wouldn't an assembler (the tool, not a person) also be a compiler?

Comment: @KellyS.French an assembler converts assembly language code to machine code, so with this definition it isn't a compiler. If, however, you have a tool that converts one assembly language into another (e.g. ARBfp1.0 to native assembly language of a modern GPU), this tool is a compiler (with this definition).

Comment: @gnasher729 - nitpick: by most definitions, the "Assembly language" part of (2) is unnecessary (notably, things like the typescript compiler or the java compiler, neither of which compile the source to assembly, but compile to javascript or java bytecode respectively). More recently it generally means any tool which compiles one programming language into another programming language (and assembly is technically a programming language).

Comment: @KellyS.French: A compiler is a program that translates a program in language X into a semantically equivalent program in language Y. Depending on what exactly the languages X and Y are, we have special names for those compilers, and "assembler" is one of those special names. But they are all special kinds of compilers. E.g. if Y = assembly and X is higher-level than Y, then we call it an assembler. If Y = assembly and X is *lower*-level than Y, we call it a disassembler. If X is lower-level than Y and Y != assembly, we call it a de-compiler. If X and Y are the same level, recent usage would …

Comment: … call it a "transpiler". If X and Y are the same language, but the output is more efficient than the input, we call it an "optimizer". If X = Y, and the output is intended to be non-readable by humans, we call it an "obfuscator". If X = Y and the output is optimized for storage space, we call it a "minifier". And so on. We could go further and also call linters, static analyzers, formatters, and colorizers "compilers", since they actually contain large part of what makes a compiler (minus the code generation part), but that would probably be too confusing.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the discussion.  I teach Programming Languages and after reading the OP & comments, the thought occurred as to whether an Assembler is a Compiler; so my comment was asked in hopes of further clarification which I got to my satisfaction (hat tip to @JörgWMittag). My comment was intended to explore the definition since the two (assembler / compiler) are so related.  I had never heard 'assembler is a type of compiler' & suspect it was simply due to assemblers being developed first. I like to find ways to connect them with the history of computing.

Comment: @KellyS.French: I guess the reason why assemblers aren't typically talked about much in terms of compilers is that assemblers are very boring compilers. At its core, an assembler is just a 1:1 mapping of human-readable mnemonics to machine-readable opcodes. The parsing stage is simple, there are no types, there are no optimizations, the code generation is trivial. None of the interesting algorithmitic stuff that compilers do is present: parsing a complex language, type checking, type inference, optimizations, clever mapping of semantics etc.

Comment: For example, the Volta compiler by Microsoft Research (long abandoned) compiled .NET MSIL byte code to ECMAScript source code, at a time when ECMAScript 3.1 was just released, so long before ECMAScript gained proper tail calls. They had to figure out how to compile .NET constructs such as generators, threads, exceptions, to ECMAScript. What they did, was to use "Volta Continuations", so all .NET control-flow was implemented in terms of Volta Continuations, and Volta Continuations were in turn implemented in terms of ECMAScript Exceptions(!!!) *That* is interesting. Mapping `JMP` to `23` isn't.

Comment: @DashaSham: In addition to this answer: Specifically, the meaning of the sentence should be that some instructions can be combined into one VLIW instruction, and which ones are up to the compiler. But if the coder can write Assembly, s/he could specify exactly which ones (presumably for a speed or size gain).

Answer (score 10):

> In VLIW architecture, the compiler/and or assembly writer chooses instructions that can be executed in parallel

The meaning of this sentence is that in VLIW architecture, assembler  (machine) code defines which instruction will be executed in parallel, so it's fixed at the time assembly code is written by a human or generated by a compiler.

This differs from super-scalar cpus, where instructions may be executed in parallel, this is a decision made by CPU each time it executes the instructions.

There are also CPUs that combine both approaches - Itanium2 is backward-compatible with Itanium, packing 3 instructions into VLIW word. But, afair, Itanium2 can execute two such packs in the single CPU cycle, and this decision is made at execution time.